# Does the StageFright vulnerability affect Facebook Messenger? What can I do about it?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I disabled MMS in Messaging on my phone. Is FB Messenger vulnerable?
If so, what can I do to minimize the risk?
(I couldn't find anything about MMS in FB Messenger)

Comment: MMS is not the only way Stagefright exploit can be run. It's one of the ways it could be run as the receiver of MMS just has to receive the MMS for the attack will start just after that. So whatever app uses the Media library will be a victim of Stage Fright. Read this article - [MMS not the only attack vector for Stagefright](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/mms-not-the-only-attack-vector-for-stagefright/)

Answer (score 1):

libStageFright is a general media library used widely on Android.  Facebook Messenger is likely to interact with it for media, and thus you are vulnerable through it.

Your best bet is to update — to a custom ROM if the manufacturer/carrier hasn't made a patch available.  Otherwise, see [Stagefright security issue: what can a regular user do to mitigate the issue without a patch?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/116473/1465)

See also: http://www.androidcentral.com/stagefright