# Why is Firefox not vulnerable to Stagefright?

Tags: stagefright

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/116675/10645) (to what can you do about Stagefright) says "use Firefox".
Why is FF not vulnerable and Chrome is?

Comment: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2015-55/

Answer (score 2):

[Firefox have used Android's StageFright Media Library](http://www.eweek.com/developer/mozilla-firefox-for-android-adds-html5-h.264-video-playback) which is disabled by default in Firefox for Android after the stage fright issue is found in Android devices. So the Firefox browser tries to use the Hardware decoder first and then the software decoder as a fallback. You can see the `about:config` page and search for `stagefright` keyword. Based on [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/h264-video-in-firefox-for-android/),

> If Firefox does not recognize your hardware decoder, it will use a
>   safer (but slower) software decoder. Daring users can manually enable
>   hardware decoding. Enter about:config as described above and search
>   for “stagefright”. To force hardware video decoding, change the
>   “media.stagefright.omxcodec.flags” preference to 16. The default value
>   is 0, which will try the hardware decoder and fall back to the
>   software decoder if there are problems ([Bug 797225](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=797225)). The most
>   likely problems you will encounter are [videos with green lines](https://bug797364.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=667489) or
>   crashes.

So if you are using Firefox make sure that the `about:config` values for the flags `media.stagefright.omxcodec.flags` and `stagefright.disabled` and `stagefright.force-enabled` stays default (i.e. 0, false, false).

[image: Screenshot_Firefox_about:config-stagefright]

<sub>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sub>

While Zimperium zLabs' VP of Platform Research and Exploitation, Joshua J. Drake hasn't said not to use Chrome. But he has suggested that Firefox is your best bet to avoid hacking by browser in [his tweet](https://twitter.com/jduck/status/625730553354940416).

Comment: us to clarify:   stagefright.disabled = false, correct?
(seems poorly named setting.   Disabled=false would mean *true* to me.)

Comment: Yes, `stagefright.disable = false` is correct and is the default value. Updated the answer with screenshot with default values of a freshly installed Firefox.