# Can I get Stagefright from a friend?

Tags: stagefright

So let's say my friend is infected with the Stagefright bug, if he sends me a video/sound will I get the virus too? Also, can voice messages on whatsapp be infected?

Answer (score 6):

No, Stagefright doesn't work like that. It's not like computer virus/worm which can spread to other device, but it's an **OS vulnerability**.

It depends only if your device has been patched or not (e.g. OS update/security update). If it has, then you can be pretty sure that such MMS won't affect your device (for particular Stagefright attack vector. AFAIK, there are multiple, not only one).

For further reading, see [Stagefright security issue: what can a regular user do to mitigate the issue without a patch?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116473/stagefright-security-issue-what-can-a-regular-user-do-to-mitigate-the-issue-wit)

Comment: Well, to be clear, if OP's devices is vulnerable to StageFright, then the fact that his friend was infected via the StageFright vulnerability vastly increase the chances of also being infected by it. So, as you pointed out, the answer hinges on whether or not OP's phone is vulnerable, but that's different from the implication I read from the first sentence.